# Apply Multi-argument models on nested tibble (invoke_map tidyverse R)

Tags: r, tidyverse, purrr

On the one hand I have some **nested data in R**.
On the other hand I have several **nls functions** that I want to test in this data.

**I am asking for a tidy workflow that allows me to cross all the nls formulas, with many starting points of several arguments, for each of the categories of the nested data.**

The functions may share arguments or not.

As far as I have reached, I have managed to generalize the formulas, with a `possibly` but `the issue is I cannot touch the arguments of each nls function. (the starting points)

I put an example with Iris data and 2 functions. There are 6 combinations but I have to insist that I am looking for generalization.

```
#Iris Nested data-----
iris_nested <- iris %>% 
  group_by(Species) %>%  
  nest() %>%  
  ungroup()

#NLS functions  -----
## Weird function 1 -----
weird_test_1 <- function(Species_data, Petal.Length_0 = 0 ){
  nls(
    Petal.Length ~ Petal.Length_0 * (1 - exp( -Petal.Width/(Sepal.Length+Sepal.Width) )),
    start = list(
      Petal.Length_0 = Petal.Length_0),
    data = Species_data
  )
}
## Weird function 2 -----
weird_test_2 <- function(Species_data, Sepal.Length_0 = 0 ){
  nls(
    Petal.Length ~ Sepal.Length_0 * (1 - exp( -(Sepal.Length+Sepal.Width)/Petal.Width )),
    start = list(
      Sepal.Length_0 = Sepal.Length_0),
    data = Species_data
  )
}

#Iteration over the model with a map_df -----
# I create a function that given a function name and a Species data allows to iterate 

fn_model <- function(.model, df){
  # safer to avoid non-standard evaluation
  # df %>% mutate(model = map(data, .model)) 
  df %>% 
    mutate('model'= map(data, possibly(.model, NULL)))
}


# here is where I stop, due to I cannot find a way to implemnet invoke_map and manipulate starting arguments:

list(
  'weird_test_1' = weird_test_1,
  'weird_test_2' = weird_test_2) %>%
  map_df(fn_model, iris_nested, .id = "id_model")
```

I tried solutions with `crossing` or tribbles but does not seem to work all together due to incompatibility of functions arguments

Comment: its unclear how you want to stipulate which starting arguments should be used for which weird test. or are you looking for advice on that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you can use this as a basis and extend it as needed.

```
library(tidyverse)

#Iris Nested data-----
iris_nested <- iris |> 
  group_by(Species) |>  
  nest() |>  
  ungroup()

#NLS functions  -----
## Weird function 1 -----
weird_test_1 <- function(Species_data, Petal.Length_0 = 0 ){
  nls(
    Petal.Length ~ Petal.Length_0 * (1 - exp( -Petal.Width/(Sepal.Length+Sepal.Width) )),
    start = list(
      Petal.Length_0 = Petal.Length_0),
    data = Species_data
  )
}
## Weird function 2 -----
weird_test_2 <- function(Species_data, Sepal.Length_0 = 0 ){
  nls(
    Petal.Length ~ Sepal.Length_0 * (1 - exp( -(Sepal.Length+Sepal.Width)/Petal.Width )),
    start = list(
      Sepal.Length_0 = Sepal.Length_0),
    data = Species_data
  )
}
#Iteration over the model with a map_df -----
# I create a function that given a function name and a Species data allows to iterate 

fn_model <- function(.model, df,...){
  safe_model <- possibly(.model)
  df |> 
    mutate('model'= map(data, \(d)safe_model(d,...))) 
}


# here is where I stop, due to I cannot find a way to implemnet invoke_map and manipulate starting arguments:

Petal.Length_0_starts <- c(0,2,4)
Sepal.Length_0_starts <- c(1,3,5)

(to_do <- tibble(start_var_name=c(rep("Petal.Length_0",3),
                            rep("Sepal.Length_0",3)),
           start_var_val = c(0,2,4,1,3,5)))

(to_do <- mutate(to_do,
                 fname = case_when(
                   startsWith(start_var_name,"Petal")~"weird_test_1",
                                   .default = "weird_test_2")))
library(rlang)
to_do$result <- pmap(to_do,
                     \(start_var_name,start_var_val ,fname){
                 
    args_to_use <- list2(.model=get(fname),
                    df=iris_nested,
                    !!sym(start_var_name):=start_var_val)

       do.call(fn_model,
               args = args_to_use)
     })

to_do
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```r
library(tidyverse)

iris_nested <- iris %>% 
  group_by(Species) %>%  
  nest() %>%  
  ungroup()

weird_test_1 <- function(Species_data, Petal.Length_0 = 0 ){
  nls(
    Petal.Length ~ Petal.Length_0 * (1 - exp( -Petal.Width/(Sepal.Length+Sepal.Width) )),
    start = list(
      Petal.Length_0 = Petal.Length_0),
    data = Species_data
  )
}

weird_test_2 <- function(Species_data, Sepal.Length_0 = 0 ){
  nls(
    Petal.Length ~ Sepal.Length_0 * (1 - exp( -(Sepal.Length+Sepal.Width)/Petal.Width )),
    start = list(
      Sepal.Length_0 = Sepal.Length_0),
    data = Species_data
  )
}

fn_model <- function(.model, df){
  df %>% 
    mutate('model'= map(data, possibly(.model, NULL)))
}

lst <- list(
  'weird_test_1' = weird_test_1,
  'weird_test_2' = weird_test_2)

map(lst, \(x) {
  fn_model(x, iris_nested)
  }) |> 
  list_rbind(names_to = "id")
#> # A tibble: 6 × 4
#>   id           Species    data              model 
#>   <chr>        <fct>      <list>            <list>
#> 1 weird_test_1 setosa     <tibble [50 × 4]> <nls> 
#> 2 weird_test_1 versicolor <tibble [50 × 4]> <nls> 
#> 3 weird_test_1 virginica  <tibble [50 × 4]> <nls> 
#> 4 weird_test_2 setosa     <tibble [50 × 4]> <nls> 
#> 5 weird_test_2 versicolor <tibble [50 × 4]> <nls> 
#> 6 weird_test_2 virginica  <tibble [50 × 4]> <nls>
```

<sup>Created on 2024-03-13 with [reprex v2.1.0](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: How can I manipulate the starting argument by this logic? My issues is I want to run many starting points

Comment: Could you give an example please?